# keras load_model raise error when executed a second time

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm making a website, and sometimes, it calls a keras neural network.
So I have a function that looks like that :

```
def network(campaign):
    from keras.models import load_model
    model = load_model("sunshade/neural_network/model.h5") #the line that fail the second time i call it

    #loading some data

    label = model.predict(images, batch_size = 128, verbose = 1)

    #some unrelated code...
```

This code works fine when I execute it the first time, but when I try to run a second time, it fails wieh this error :

```
Exception in thread Thread-31:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 930, in _run
    allow_operation=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2414, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2493, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Tensor %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", shape=(32,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/SpyNet/poc/sunshadeDetector/sunshade/models.py", line 46, in launch_network
    network(self)
  File "/home/ec2-user/SpyNet/poc/sunshadeDetector/sunshade/neural_network/network.py", line 27, in network
    model = load_model("sunshade/neural_network/model.h5")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 236, in load_model
    topology.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f['model_weights'], model.layers)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 3048, in load_weights_from_hdf5_group
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2188, in batch_set_value
    get_session().run(assign_ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 933, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder_3:0", shape=(32,), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

By the way, I use django for the website part, but i don't think it's related.
There must be some kind of thing that need to be closed, or re-initialized... I tried to use tf.Session(), and tf.reset_default_graph,but I still get errors.
So now I have to restart my django server each time i want to use this function.

Do you have any idea ? In worst case scenario, may be I can make the model a singleton, so that i don't have to reload it each time...

Comment: My approach has been to load the model in the main thread (using Flask, falcon) and and give the routes this model (like you mentioned in the last sentence). Otherwise try this issue: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397

Comment: I've encountered the same error before, and the method described in the link provided by @putonspectacles fixed it. Specifically, I used `with K.get_session().graph.as_default() as g: model = load_model(...)`.

Comment: Okay, I tested that. with singleton way, or K.get_session... my webserver doesn't crash any more. But it's not exactly what I want... What I really want is a way to train my network on the machine, while the webserver is up (it's okay that it can't use a network while it's training). Now I can't because, keras/tensorflow seems to still use memory in my gpu when its job is finished. Therefore I don't have enough memory to train it. It's not a major issue, but I'm looking for a way to "stop" completely keras/tensorflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new sesstion and load the model to it.

```
from keras.models import load_model
import keras

def network(campaign):
    with keras.backend.get_session().graph.as_default():
        model = load_model("sunshade/neural_network/model.h5")
        label = model.predict(images, batch_size = 128, verbose = 1)
```

Comment: I'm getting Error: `keras.backend has no get_session() attribute` !!!

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue when loading the graph with different thread i.e generally in the web-services.

Below is the my approach to resolve it:

While loading or constructing your model, save the TensorFlow graph:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

In the other thread (or perhaps in an asynchronous event handler), I do:

```
global graph
with graph.as_default():
   # some predict or .....
```

I learn and resolved my problem by read below issues:

1. https://github.com/Breta01/handwriting-ocr/issues/98
2. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397